# System PHP version upgraded to 7.3 but domain is stuck at 7.2

Tags: php, cpanel, whm, centos

I recently upgraded PHP from 7.2 to 7.3 on my Centos and Apache server by using cPanel/WHM. I'd updated the System PHP version to 7.3 but the domain is still stuck at 7.2. When I attempt to upgrade the domain's version (or set to inherit) I'm given an error.

```
Error: (XID vq7kma) 1 error occurred: Error #1: The system failed to apply the “PHP” version to “mydomain.com”: Cpanel::Exception::IO::ChownError/(XID ybmdsv) The system failed to set the user ID to “1000” and the group ID to “99” on “GLOB(0x310d010)” because of an error: Operation not permitted at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/FileUtils/Access.pm line 78.

Cpanel::FileUtils::Access::ensure_mode_and_owner(GLOB(0x310d010), 420, 1000, 99) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transaction/File/Base.pm line 202 

Cpanel::Transaction::File::Base::_set_permissions(GLOB(0x310d010), 420, ARRAY(0x30de3f0), 416) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transaction/File/Base.pm line 417 

Cpanel::Transaction::File::Base::__ANON__(GLOB(0x310d010), __CPANEL_HIDDEN__..., 416) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/SafeFile/Replace.pm line 94 

Cpanel::SafeFile::Replace::locked_atomic_replace_contents(GLOB(0x3088878), Cpanel::SafeFileLock=ARRAY(0x310d358), CODE(0x3088ba8)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transaction/File/Base.pm line 430 

Cpanel::Transaction::File::Base::_save_or_die(Cpanel::Transaction::File::Raw=HASH(0x3088890), "offset", 0, "write_cr", CODE(0x2f547b0)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transaction/File/Raw.pm line 76 Cpanel::Transaction::File::Raw::save_or_die(Cpanel::Transaction::File::Raw=HASH(0x3088890)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transaction/File/Base.pm line 272 eval {...} called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Transaction/File/Base.pm line 272 

Cpanel::Transaction::File::Base::save_and_close_or_die(Cpanel::Transaction::File::Raw=HASH(0x3088890)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/WebServer/Supported/apache/Htaccess.pm line 204 

Cpanel::WebServer::Supported::apache::Htaccess::_internal_set_handler(Cpanel::WebServer::Supported::apache::Htaccess=HASH(0x2fb8210), "lang", Cpanel::ProgLang::Supported::php=HASH(0x2e2c8d8), "handler", Cpanel::WebServer::Supported::apache::Handler::cgi=HASH(0x2e563c0), "vhost", "mydomain.com", "userdata", ...) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/WebServer/Supported/apache/Htaccess.pm line 212 

Cpanel::WebServer::Supported::apache::Htaccess::__ANON__() called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/AccessIds/ReducedPrivileges.pm line 96 eval {...} called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/AccessIds/ReducedPrivileges.pm line 96
```

I've tried both WHM and cPanel to make the upgrade to no success. Does anyone know how to correct the issue? The errors hint at permissions but that's all I can glean from it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted your hosting tech support?  It is showing a CHOWN error so it looks like an ownership issue.

Comment: I did contact them but it's an unmanaged account and they seem a bit hands off. I think I'll push on them a little more to see if they can help. Thanks!